# IDLE 3.5 won't open

Tags: python, python-idle, python-3.5

I'm really confused. For some reason, I suddenly can't open IDLE 3.5. I have tried uninstalling it and reinstlling, but no luck. I was told to delete the folder `.idlerc` but it hasn't come back after constant tries. Was that a huge mistake? I have no idea what's going on.

Comment: here a lot smilar questions. Idle not a app ! Ex:`c:\Python25\pythonw.exe c:\Python25\Lib\idlelib\idle.py` what are you missing ? `idle.py` or `python.exe` ?

Comment: @dsgdfg Ummm... What? Idle is an app. It's an IDE. It's packaged, and it comes with python by default.

Comment: How are you trying to open IDLE?  If you open from a console with `python -m idlelib`, what happens?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Python crashes...

Comment: It 'crashes' when you do what? and what are you seeing that you call a 'crash'?  On what OS?

Comment: @TerryJanReedy Sorry, I know you've been trying to help, but I'm not gonna be working on this any more, since I'm gonna be using a VM.

Answer (score 0):

Is it just the IDE? Or the python install itself?

When having problems using IDLE as an IDE I would recommend using [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/). It offers imho the best options for Python developing.

Comment: Just the IDE, but to be honest I've kinda abandoned this question. I think it's high time I open a VM with Linux. Thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: You're welcome Thats the next thing, I would also recommend using Linux ;) (By the way, PyCharm is available for Linux also).

Answer (score 0):

A common cause of failure of idle startup is a user-written file with the same name as a standard library module, such as **random.py** and **tkinter.py.**

First make sure you dont have a file named **random.py** and **tkinter.py** in the current folder.

All the [startup failures of idle are described here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/idle.html#:%7E:text=A%20common%20cause%20of%20failure,to%20rename%20the%20user%20file.).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.  Turned out I had a python program named 'random.py'.  Idle would not run until I renamed that program!